# How do I develop drop down menus so they display images like Amazon and Walmart in Magento?

Tags: image, magento, drop-down-menu

Anyone know how I can develop drop down menus so they display images like Amazon and Walmart in Magento?

[image: Walmart's Drop down menu with side image]

And Amazon's:

[image: Amazon's Drop Down Menu]

Thank you,
Jae

Comment: Hi, I want to add a disclaimer: I've learned that you can install from either developers or from third-party software vendors "Mega Menu" plug-ins or extensions. They are readily available online, as well as from Magento Connect. Search "mega menu Magento" online and it'll result in many resources both free and commercial. I'd love to hear how it can be developed through code, however.

Answer (score 0):

To develop the same feature you can install the free extension which magento community provide.
for example:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/responsive-custom-menu.html
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mega-menu-best-navigation-extension.html